# How can i paint/highlight the line i m reading in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I'm building a web site and i want to paint/highlight the line that i m reading.
here is my code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow rw in gvHastalar.Rows)
 {
    rw.CssClass = "gvKontrolEdilenSatir";
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i m looping in a foreach (look my code) and i want to painting that i m reading row in that loop.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to highlight a row when you hover over it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a particular row selected in the GridView you can compare the index of the current row in the foreach loop with the `SelectedIndex` of the GridView.  You can then conditionally set the CSS class if they match.

```
foreach (GridViewRow rw in gvHastalar.Rows)
{
    if (rw.RowIndex == gvHastalar.SelectedIndex)
        rw.CssClass = "SelectedCssClass";
    else
        rw.CssClass = "NotSelectedCssClass";
}
```